# NumLock doesn't work with combo of keys

Tags: unicode, unicode-entry

I use **a lot** Unicode characters, and numeric keypad doesn't work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Ubuntu 17.10 (but I remember it's this way since 16.04).
NumLock works reversed. That's not good.
I'm a little desperate.

Comment: Try to find this options somewhere in GNOME Tweaks (`gnome-tweak`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works. Just Use the combo of keys above, select the corresponding Unicode code with numeric keypad **and press** <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Anyway, Gnome Tweaks is **so** useful (why it's not default/preinstalled??!?) I recommend it to **everyone**.